# Custom keras loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras with tensorflow backend and I'm trying to write a custom keras loss function and I need to calculate the f1 score for each of my classes (I have 4 classes) the problem is when I write the code I get an error while compiling the model since the `y_true` and `y_pred` are Placeholders while the model is compiling and for that I can't use scikit-learn to calculate the f1 score.
The usual answer to the problem is to use keras backend built-in functions for custom loss but it seems a bit hard to use them for per class f1 score calculation.
I would appreciate any help on the matter :)

```py
def F1_Loss(y_true,y_pred):
    y_true = K.eval(y_true)
    y_pred = K.eval(y_pred)
    f1_vector = sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true,to_categorical(np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1),num_classes=4),average=None)
    return np.mean(f1_vector)
```

Comment: Could you attach the code that you are using to this answer?

Comment: @alexyorke the code is not complete and the np.mean() part is just for testing but I can't get it to work this far in order to implement the rest

Comment: To backprop through your loss, it has to be written using Keras backend functions. I think the answer here https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45165/how-to-get-accuracy-f1-precision-and-recall-for-a-keras-model will probably work.

Comment: @OllinBoerBohan thanks for the answer I tried this approach but the code in that answer doesn't calculate the measures for each class and that's where I'm stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem I post it here in case anyone has the same problem

```py
def F1_Vector(y_true,y_pred):
    tp = K.sum(K.cast(y_true*y_pred, 'float'), axis=0)
    tn = K.sum(K.cast((1-y_true)*(1-y_pred), 'float'), axis=0)
    fp = K.sum(K.cast((1-y_true)*y_pred, 'float'), axis=0)
    fn = K.sum(K.cast(y_true*(1-y_pred), 'float'), axis=0)
    p = tp / (tp + fp + K.epsilon())
    r = tp / (tp + fn + K.epsilon())
    f1 = 2*p*r / (p+r+K.epsilon())
    f1_vector = (tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(f1), tf.zeros_like(f1), f1))
    return f1_vector
```